# Optimization function for the sum Google Maps distance

Tags: python, matrix, maps, distance, minimize

I am trying to find a point (latitude/longitude) that minimizes the sum of Google maps distance to all other N points.

I was able to extract the Google Maps distances between my latitude and longitude arrays but I wasn't able to minimize my function.

**Code**

```
def minimize_g(input_g):
    gmaps1 = googlemaps.Client(key="xxx") 


def distance_f(x):
    dist = gmaps1.distance_matrix([x], np.array(input_g)[:,1:3])
    sum_ = 0
    for obs in range(len(np.array(df[:3]))):
        sum_+= dist['rows'][0]['elements'][obs]['distance']['value']   
    return sum_

 #initial guess: centroid
centroid = input_g.mean(axis=0)

optimization = minimize(distance_f, centroid, method='COBYLA')

return optimization.x
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for any point on the map that results in shortest distance to all coordinates in your list, you can try writing a function that calculates the distance from one coordinate to another coordinate. If you have that function ready to go, its a matter of calculating the total distance to all your points from a test point.

Then, from some artificially created coordinates, you would minimize the distances to all your points with something along the lines of

```
import numpy as np

lats = [12.3, 12.4, 12.5]
lons = [16.1, 15.1, 14.1]

def total_distance_to_lats_and_lons(lat, lon):
    # some summation over distances from lat, lon to lats, lons

# create two lists with 0.01 degree precision as an artificial grid of possibilities
test_lats = np.arange(min(lats), max(lats), 0.01)
test_lons = np.arange(min(lons), max(lons), 0.01)

test_distances = []  # empty list to fill with the total_distance to each combination of test_lat, test_lon
coordinate_index_combinations = []  # corresponding coordinates
for test_lat in test_lats:
    for test_lon in test_lons:
        coordinate_combinations.append([test_lat, test_lon])  # add a combination of indices
        test_distances.append(total_distance_to_lats_and_lons(test_lat, test_lon))  # add a distance

index_of_best_test_coordinate = np.argmin(test_distances)  # find index of the minimum value
print('Best match is index {}'.format(index_of_best_test_coordinate))
print('Coordinates: {}'.format(coordinate_combinations[index_of_best_test_coordinate]))
print('Total distance: {}'.format(test_distances[index_of_best_test_coordinate]))
```

This brute force approach has some precision limitations and becomes an expensive loop quite quickly, so you can also apply this method iteratively with the minimum found after each round, so iteratively increasing precision and decreasing start and end points in the test coordinate lists. After a few iterations, you should have a pretty precise estimate. On the other hand, it is possible such an iterative method converges to one of multiple local minima, yielding only one of multiple solutions.